# Problem passing child to parent with SRC of image. REACT JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, image, components

How are you?

My situation is the next. I am passing an array with information to a Component to render with a map().
The name and title are perfect for me.

But I have trouble passing the SRC of the image. I've already tried all the ways I could think of, but nothing.

In the array I leave different paths that I have tried and nothing.
Thaanks!

MY COMPONENT:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TeampeopleData } from '../Components/TeampeopleData';



function Aboutus() {
    return (
        <div className='about'>

                <div className="about-text">
                    <h1 className='about-text-title'>ABOUT US</h1>
                    <h2 className="about-text-big">We work until we see the invisible</h2>
                    <h2 className="about-text-small">Because it is our passion to serve our clients to the utmost satisfaction, we go against all odds to meet your expectations. We can’t promise you the world but here’s one thing we can assure you: We like to be as clear as we possibly can. We’ll hound you – one, two, three meetings – as many as it takes to get it right! We’re not perfectionists. We just want to make YOU the happiest.
                    </h2>
                </div>
            <div className="about-team">
                <h2 className="about-team-title">Our Team</h2>
                <div className="about-team-people">
                    {TeampeopleData.map((item)=>{
                        return(
                            <div className='people'>
                                <div className="people-img">
                                    <img src={item.photo} alt="team-people" className="team-people-photo"/>
                                </div>
                                <h2 className="people-name">{item.name}</h2>
                                <p className="people-title">{item.title}</p>
                            </div>
                        )

                    })}
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    )
}

export default Aboutus
```

MY ARRAY

```
import people1 from '../img/people1.jpg';


export const TeampeopleData =[

    {
        photo: {people1},
        name: 'Blas Garcia',
        title: 'Founder'
    },
    {
        photo: '/src/img/people1.jpg',
        name: 'Patrick O’donnel',
        title: 'Marketing'
    },
    {
        photo: '../img/people1.jpg',
        name: 'Olivia Wralikszowa',
        title: 'Art Director'
    }

]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bnz7K.png)

Comment: You need to add these images to the public or compiled  folder where your compiler is adding the app.js code. and use the image like 
  `{
        photo: './img/people1.jpg',
        name: 'Olivia Wralikszowa',
        title: 'Art Director'
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the bracket around the people1 and it'll work fine.

```
{
    photo: people1,
    name: 'Blas Garcia',
    title: 'Founder'
},
```